# TinyMce custom Formatting

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I am looking for two scenarios

1. Customize the bullets button(Clicking should appear `<li class="myBullets"></li>`.
2. In each new line or Enter, i like to add `<div class="newline"></div>` instead of default `<p></p>` tags.

I tried like this,

tinymce.init({

```
    toolbar: "undo redo bold italic bullist",
    formats: {
        bold: { inline: 'span', 'classes': 'bold,mytestClass' }, // This worked
        // bullist: { inline: 'span','classes': 'MybulletClass' } //failed
    },
    forced_root_block: 'div' // In each enter new div is created but how can I add classes?
});
```

How can i achieve this?